# upper and lower sum answer not matching

Tags: calculus

I have to show that f is integrable using the Riemann criterion where
f(x) = x on [0, 1]. I am a bit confused over how my solution differs from the hint to solution of that question I have.
**My approach is below**:

Let partition P = {0 , 1/n , 2/n , ..... , (n-1)/n , n/n}.

So, U(P,f) = ∑(1/n) . { f(1/n) + f(2/n) + ....... + f(n/n) }
And, L(p,f) = ∑(1/n) . { f(0) + f(2/n) + ....... + f(n-1/n) }
Then, U(P,f) - L(P,f) = ( f(n/n) - f(0) )/n 
                      = 1/n -> 0

**Hint to solution given :**
[image: link is here]

I am very confused over how did they get the result 1/n² , instead of my 1/n . Please help me out.

Comment: I believe the hint is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct. The idea in the hint (sum first then subtract; instead of subtract first, then sum) is valid, but it gets the details wrong. The correct calculation is:

$$ U(P_n,f) ~~=~~ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac1n \cdot \frac{i}{n} ~~=~~ \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n i ~~=~~ \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}  $$

and similarly $L(P_n,f) = \frac{1}{n^2}\cdot \frac{(n-1)n}{2}$.

Comment: This answer exists to remove this question from the Unanswered queue. Please upvote or choose Best Answer to complete this process.